# ExpressJS Static not working

Tags: node.js, express

Been having some issues with express, I can't seem to serve static files.
If I do :

```
app.use('/*', express.static(DIST_FILEPATH));
```

it gives me a `301` or something, basically doesn't find the file (I have tried it in incognito mode also to avoid chasing/whatever issues).

But for some reason if I do:

```
app.use('/*', function (req, res, next) {
     console.log(req.originalUrl);
    console.log(DIST_FILEPATH);
    res.sendFile(path.join(DIST_FILEPATH, req.originalUrl));
});
```

It works just fine and both paths are correct. Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Express version: 4.14.1

Comment: You don't need to specify a route path for static file serving, just use: `app.use(express.static(DIST_FILEPATH));`

Comment: @mscdex I do have 3 static file paths ( node modules, public and dist) but adding dist without a path at the end might work :-?

Comment: Yes you just need to use `app.use(express.static(DIST_FILEPATH));`  and it will only server dist files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you have the syntax slightly off. What you can do if you want to only server static files is use `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));` then when you go to `http://localhost:3000/` you can add things like `index.html` so that you can see your `html` file. Here is an example of a simple express server that serves static files:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.set('port', 3000);


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname))); //here you can change your path. for example you could add + 'public' if all of your files where in the 'public' directory

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  var port = server.address().port;
});
```

You can run this with `node <filename>.js` then just go to `http://localhost:3000/index.html` or `http://localhost:3000/myMusicFile.mp3` for example.

hope this helps!

Comment: in my case, this working on localhost. but not at production server with port 3000 with https